# TypeError: formats.dateTimeString.toISOString is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and AngularJS, and I'm trying to convert a date from my API that is something like:

```
"8/22/2015"
```

...to an ISO Date.  The date is properly deserialized into a TypeScript property of type `Date`.  However, when I try the following command (in typescript, and `this.dateDisplay` is of type string)

```
this.dateDisplay = formats.dateTimeValue.toISOString();
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: formats.dateTimeValue.toISOString is not a function
>       at dataFormatsTests.js:42
>       at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
>       at angular.js:14583
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15657)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15951)
>       at done (angular.js:10364)
>       at completeRequest (angular.js:10536)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10477)

I've also been to [this site](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) and it says my browser supports the `toISOString` function.

So, my questions is: Why doesn't my browser, or angular, or whatever, recognize the `toISOString` function?

Comment: Are you sure that `formats.dateTimeString` is a _Date_ object? It seems that it isn't _Date_ object since _toISOString_ isn't a function.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a Date.  Poor choice of property name on my part (I've been through a few iterations trying to get this to work, and I didn't update the property name).  I'll edit my question to make it more clear.  Thanks!

Comment: What does it show if you do something like `alert(formats.dateTimeString.toString());` or use `console.error(..);` if that suits better your usage.

Comment: That's a type error, so it doesn't really matter whether it's actually a `Date` or not, since either way TypeScript doesn't think it is a `Date`. Go to where `dateTimeValue` is defined and make sure its type is `Date`. You can check the implementation afterwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the dateTimeValue was defined as a Date in TypeScript, it was being instantiated at runtime as a string because it was being pulled from the API.  Therefore, the TypeScript would compile just fine, but when the javascript ran it was seeing `.toISOString()` being called against a string, not a Date.

Comment: I just came back to check, and actually I got it backwards, but I'm glad it helped in some way then :)

Answer (score 2):

Moment.js creates a wrapper for the Date object.formats.dateTimeValue is not wrapper object. To get this wrapper object, simply call moment() with one of the supported input types. so convert it like this:

```
this.dateDisplay = moment(formats.dateTimeValue).toISOString();
```

I have solved my problem like above.